# Django Serializer showing "character": "Dictionary object (256)" as opposed to the actual character

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django rest framework and I am trying to do a JOIN on a GET command.

I have the following view:

```
class CharacterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, user_id):
        character_saves = Char.objects.select_related('character').filter(
            user_id=user_id)
        serializer = CharacterSerializer(character_saves, many=True)
        return Response({"characters": serializer.data})
```

And the following serializer:

```
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    character_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    active = serializers.BooleanField()
    character = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Char.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=validated_data.pop('user_id'),
            character_id=validated_data.pop('character_id'),
            defaults=validated_data
        )
```

Yet, I am getting the following data:

```
"characters": [
    {
        "character_id": 256,
        "user_id": 1,
        "active": true,
        "character": "Dictionary object (256)"
    },
    {
        "character_id": 260,
        "user_id": 1,
        "active": true,
        "character": "Dictionary object (260)"
    }
]
```

Instead of giving me the actual item I want, it gives me a dictionary object. This is almost correct, however I am guessing I am configuring something wrong in my query or serializer, preventing me from getting the raw value.

How do I get the actual value here, rather than "Dictionary object (260)"?

Char model:

```
class Char(models.Model):
    character = models.ForeignKey(
        Dictionary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

Dictionary model:

```
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    traditional = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    simplified = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pinyin_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pinyin_marks = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    translation = models.TextField()
    level = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'dictionary'
```

Comment: can you share your models ?

Comment: @Md.TanvirRaihan Added it

Comment: Ideally I'd like to put several fields from dictionary into the serialized output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specified a `CharField` for the `Dictionary` relation, it's trying to get the string representation of your `Dictionary` model. One way you could fix it is to set the `str` representation on the model:

```py
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.traditional
```

Alternatively, you should be able to alter the `source` of the `character` field on your serializer to instead pull from a property from the relation.

```py
class CharacterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...
    character = serializers.CharField(source="character.traditional")
```

Answer (score 2):

tredzko's answer is correct, but you have asked in the comment box that `you like to put several fields from dictionary into the serialized output`, so for that part you can do like this,

```
Class DictionarySerializer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Dictionary
        fields = (....) # Your specified fields goes here

class CharacterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    character_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    active = serializers.BooleanField()
    character = DictionarySerializer() # simply add this
```

**EDIT**: No need to override the `create` method.

Comment: This can also be done with more character fields with different sources on the `CharacterSerializer` as well (to avoid having nested values if desired). That said, I agree, making a serializer specifically for that would probably be better if it would be reused or being nested would be ok or even desired.